# What is @SkipSelf decorator in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-decorator, angular-injector

The @SkipSelf decorator tells DI to look for a dependency in the whole tree starting from the parent injector

I came across the @SkipSelf decorator as below. What does this `@SkipSelf`decorator exactly mean in this case?

```
class Dependency {}

@Injectable()
class NeedsDependency {
  constructor(@SkipSelf() public dependency: Dependency) { this.dependency = dependency; }
}

const parent = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([Dependency]);
const child = parent.resolveAndCreateChild([NeedsDependency]);
expect(child.get(NeedsDependency).dependency instanceof Dependency).toBe(true);

const inj = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([Dependency, NeedsDependency]);
expect(() => inj.get(NeedsDependency)).toThrowError();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start line by line:

**The first case:**

**A.** Create parent injector and add `Dependency` to it:

```
const parent = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([Dependency]);
```

**B.** Create child injector and add `NeedsDependency` to it, since `Dependency` is provided in parent injector, the DI framework can resolve `NeedsDependency`'s  dependencies (`Dependency`)

```
const child = parent.resolveAndCreateChild([NeedsDependency]);
```

**The second case:**

**A.** Create a single injector and add both `Dependency` & `NeedsDependency` to it:

```
const inj = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([Dependency, NeedsDependency]);
```

**B.** This time resolving `NeedsDependency`'s dependencies will fail, due to `@SkipSelf()` being applied to `Dependency`, DI framework will ignore the `Dependency` instance within `inj` injector, and try looking up the hierarchy to find a provider that satisfies this dependency which doesn't exist, therefore `inj.get(NeedsDependency)` will throw an error as `NeedsDependency` can't be resolved.

```
expect(() => inj.get(NeedsDependency)).toThrowError();
```